# Set explicit time with date

Tags: date, timestamps, time

When I tried to set time with

`$(date +%s -d "2022-04-10 12:12:12")`

I get the time

`2022-04-10 19:12:12`

How can I set the time explicit?

Comment: Thanks to add expected output. I get `1649567532`

Comment: Just `2022-04-10 12:12:12`

Comment: If you ran the command you say you ran you would have received the error message, `1649589132: command not found`. What did you actually run?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Comment: @GillesQuénot done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
date '+%F %T' -d "2022-04-10 12:12:12"
2022-04-10 12:12:12
```

Check:

```
man 3 strftime
```

Comment: Thanks.........